# transformar un número entero en una cadena con el signo y los dígitos

Tags: c#, estructuras-de-datos, recursión

Tengo que escribir una función recursiva en C# para transformar un número entero en una cadena con el signo y los dígitos de que consta: string entroaCadena(int n). Para los números positivos me sale todo bien, el problema que tengo es que cuando tengo un numero negativo me concatena con el signo negativo, por ejemplo: si tengo -23 me dará "-2-3", como yo haría para solo dejar el caracter "-" al principio de la cadena?

```
static string entroaCadena(int n)
{            
        int d1, d2;
        string c1;

        if (n == 0)
        {
            return "" ;
        }
        else
        {               
            d1 = n % 10;
            d2 = n / 10;               
            c1 = d1.ToString();                
            n--;
            
            return entroaCadena(d2) + c1 ;
        }
```

Comment: Coloqué una respuesta a tu pregunta, me gustaría que la probaras y verificaras que resuelve tu problema y si lo crees correcto que marcaras la respuesta como aceptada y además que la puntearas si lo crees justo.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución a tu problema puede ser la siguiente:

```
   static string entroaCadena(int n)
    {
        int d1, d2;
        string c1;

        if (n == 0)
        {
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            d1 = n % 10;
            d2 = n / 10;
            if (d2 < 0) //Condición que verifica si el valor es negativo
                d1 = d1 * (-1);//Convertimos el digito extraido a un valor positivo
            c1 = d1.ToString();
            n--;
            return entroaCadena(d2) + c1;
        }
    }
```

Cuando el entero a convertir es negativo, la condición `if (d2 < 0)` se cumplirá para todos los digitos extraidos, excepto para el primer digito a la izquierda, en cuyo caso d2=0, y por tanto no se relizará la multiplicación por -1.